# Altium: Filenames with sheet numbers

Tags: altium

I have seen some examples of schematics with page numbers in the filenames of the sheets. e.g. *[01] sheetNameforSheet1.schdoc*

Do does one do it, manually or is there more elegant way of doing it? How does one do it for hierarchical design. If you shift/add/remove any page, seems like you need to change all following filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do Scheet Numbers in File names! Use functional names in the scheets like Powersupply.schdoc, CPU_digital.schdoc, CPU_supply.schdoc, Communication.schdoc, CAN.schdoc, SPI.schdoc, ...

Make a hierachical schematic design and use a header in the schematic witch has the parameters "SheetNumber" and "SheetTotal".

Use Tools -> Anotation -> "Number schematic sheets" to set the parameters of every sheet correctly. When you add or remove a sheet just run the anotation again. See
[Altium Doku](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/sch-dlg-projectparameterdialogsheet-numbering-for-project-ad)